# Solving $y^2 \equiv ax \mod bx$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, quadratics

Is there any relation between solution of y for $$y^2 \equiv ax \mod bx \text{ and }y^2 \equiv a \pmod b$$ For example  $$y^2 \equiv 30 \mod 70 $$ has solutions $10$ and $60$ but $$y^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 7$$ has no solutions.

I understand we can factorize $x$ and then by CRT we can solve for y. But can we do better than that, I mean without factorising $x$ . If $x$ is large non-prime then can we solve this $$y^2 \equiv ax \mod bx  \text{ from solutions of } y^2 \equiv a \pmod b$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $y$ must share $x$ in the first, and $\gcd(a,b)$ in the second.

Comment: y sharing x in the first ..seems good

Answer (score 1):

$y^2≡ax \mod bx $ => x divides y 
Putting $y=xy'$ 
$y^2≡ax \mod bx $  <=>  $x^2y'^2≡ax \mod bx $ 
<=> $xy'^2≡a \mod b $
<=> $y'^2≡x^{-1}a \mod b $ // inverse of x in mod b 
Now find square root of $x^{-1}a$ in mod b
Thanks to @Roddy MacPhee in comments